# jQuery Toggle - Jump to Toggle at Named Anchor and Open It

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, anchor

Here's what I'm working with http://jsfiddle.net/wajPw/

In the example, notice that there is a superscript "1" in the first sentence of Section 1.

When user clicks the "1", I'd like to jump to the "References" section at the bottom of the page, and at the same time toggle that content open. I've been able to get it to either jump to the anchor or toggle open, but not both. I've also been trying to use "window.location.hash", but not sure if that's the right approach.

Comment: Do you want to toggle the entire list of references open, or just the one that matches the one clicked on?

Comment: I want to toggle the entire References section open. idor_brad nailed it below.

Answer (score 0):

This might help get you on your way.

```
$('sup').on('click', function(){
    $('a[name="refs"]').parent().next().slideDown();
});
```

Of course, this will not toggle the li that corresponds to the number indicated, but I'm not sure if that's what you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/wajPw/1/

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks idor_brad!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will mimic the anchor jump.

```
$('a[href=#refs]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //disable the default action of jumping to the link

    //open it before we get there?
    $('a[name=refs]').parent().click(); 

    //references offset..
    var refsOffset = $('a[name=refs]').offset().top;

    //body,html animate selector is a cross-browser fix.
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: refsOffset
    });
});
```